# Oracle Database DBMS_SCHEDULER JOB How to execute job while same job is running?

Tags: oracle

I scheduled a job using DBMS_SCHEDULER by every one minute. But if there is the first executions not finished, the next job is not executed as scheduled. Is there solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute same job in parallel with an already running instance using `use_current_session` parameter of [DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#i1013568).

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.RUN_JOB(job_name => 'TEST_JOB', use_current_session => TRUE);
END;
/
```

Comment: But what if I already scheduled a job in the database? could I run that job with that parameter?

Comment: Yes you can. Give it a quick try if you can right now.